# filter varbinary field by length

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am storing ips using `VARBINARY(16)` data type. I'd like to select just the ipv4 ips. Is it possible to filter column by the lenght used in `VARBINARY` (or `VARCHAR`)? Something like this

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA(`ip`) from `TABLE` where BYTESLENGHT(`ip`) = 4
```

Comment: Is storing ips with `VARBINARY` type a strict requirement? @sanjihan

Comment: @lemon. not really, it's more of a convenience, because I do not need to use 2 columns for ipv4 and ipv6 separately.

Comment: can you provide some sample rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `LENGTH()`, which returns the length of a string in bytes. It supports both VARCHAR or VARBINARY.

```
mysql> create table mytable (ip varbinary(16));

mysql> insert into mytable set ip = inet6_aton('192.168.1.1');

mysql> insert into mytable set ip = inet6_aton('fdfe::5a55:caff:fefa:9089');

mysql> select length(ip) from mytable;
+------------+
| length(ip) |
+------------+
|          4 |
|         16 |
+------------+
```